Panaromic images to PointCloud
I am really new to photogrammetry. I need your help. I have a ton of panaromic images and a csv file that contain
the name of image, file_type sequence_id timestamp GPS_time(s) east, north, altitude attitude(x)=roll attitude(y)=pitch attitude(z)=pan frame_id
How can I generate a point cloud from these images?
The end task is to create 2d and 3d models of the area from the images. i have researched and found out that for that we need to have a point cloud first and then we can import that into Rivet and map out the area and make cad files and add prepare a GIS Database for all.
But right now any help for the first part would be highly appreciated.
I have tried using MetaShape but I can't get to properly reference the images.

Try colmap? Use exiftool to embed GPS data into image meta data.

You can check Metashape tutorial on spherical panoramas processing:
https://agisoft.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/31000161406-processing-spherical-panoramas-in-agisoft-metashape
Same approach can be applied to cylindrical panoramas, just select corresponding camera type before processing.
As for the referencing data import, you can use plain text CSV file that contains the following information for every image already added to the project:

image filename with file extension,
X coordinate (Longitude or Easting/Westing),
Y coordinate (Latitude or Northing/Southing),
Z coordinate (Altitude)

So this information should be arranged into lines with identical separator, then just use Import CSV option on the Reference pane in Metashape Pro window.
If you are using Metashape Standard, then you will not be able to reference the project, but still should be able to process the data and get point cloud and mesh model from panoramas, then just export it and reference in another program.
